# The choice of a statistical test to verify if there is significant difference between two categorical variables in a single population

Tags: stata, medicine

Hello everyone I need some help with the choice of a statistical test to verify if there is significant difference between two categorical variables in a single population.

I need to compare the success rate of surgery in a given population in STATA.

In particular, in my dataset I have a certain number of patients identified with "1" (with detrusor underactivity) opposed to 0 (with normal detrusor contractility); in the subgroup of patients with detrusor underactivity I want to know if there is a difference between success rates after surgery (yes = 0/ no = 1).

Which test should I use to verify the hypothesis that there is no difference in success rate in this subgroup of patients?

Comment: [Pearson's $\chi^{2}$ test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) (using, e.g., `cc`). Alternately, [likelihood ratio $G$ test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test) (I *think* using `lrtest`). Alternately, [*z* test of population proportions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-test) (using `prtest`). Welcome to CV.

Comment: Thank you @Alexis